# How To Make Firebug Disabled With Javascript, Jquery, Php

Tags: firebug

I am using firebug for inspect element . 
But now I want to make it disabled. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should clarify your question according to the your comment on Maxime's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top right of Firebug, you have 3 red buttons.

It's the last one, like a "power" button ...

Comment: Thanks for reply I am very happy to have reply on my question, but i want it something different. I want to make disabled y JavaScript when ever my application will run on any browser then there should be a warning pop up for disabled it or it should be disabled.

Comment: It's simply not possible ;) You cannot check things like that on client side. (You can but if they still want to use your website they'll find a way !)

Comment: Thanks once again for this, Would you suggest me something for this security reason as i have discuss with you..

Comment: If you tell me what you exactly want, yes ... :) Because be sure JS is disabled is not possible. So what do you want exactly ?

Comment: i want to prevent hidden field of form to be changed.

Comment: You cannot. It is not possible. Client can do what he wants. The only thing that can (and HAVE TO) is to check on server side (php probably) check incoming data :)

Comment: To clarify Maxime's comment: You **ALWAYS HAVE TO** check user input on the server side for security reasons. Client-side checks of input data are just a bonus. Users could create their own HTML page or modify your page on the client-side using tools like Firebug, which send invalid or harmful data like e.g. [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to your server.